# Why did the protagonist do this in the end?

Tags: brand-new-cherry-flavor

*Sorry for the all-encompassing spoiler tags, but the series has recently been released at this point, and virtually everything relevant for this question is a part of the season finale.*

At the end of [Brand New Cherry Flavor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brand_New_Cherry_Flavor)'s season 1, the protagonist

> has sorted out all the dangling plot threads by escaping from Boro, getting rid of the goons that were hired to kill her, and exerting her revenge on Lou.
>
>  Furthermore, she is contacted by financier Alvin who is happy to let her direct her movie. While their first encounter is a bit hurried, she sees him at a restaurant and makes extra-sure that she will be the director of the movie.

Yet, shortly after

> she is seen buying a one-way ticket to São Paulo, presumably to return to Brazil for good. Given that she does not care to return (or even receive) Alvin's calls about an upcoming important meeting that would lead to the production of her movie, it seems she has suddenly given up on her movie project (and possibly even on her entire filmmaking career) just when it was about to start over.

**Why would she do that?**

*It is possible the series intended to make her actions incomprehensible and seemingly irrational, in which case this is of course a valid answer. However, I presume I mussed have missed something that was maybe not very clearly explained on the show, but was meant to be understood by viewers (?)*